# How to identify the framework or dependency which are using microphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods

When I submit my app to apple store, I get below messages after API usage analyse.I don't intend to use these feature, so I'm wondering can I work out which framework or dependency are using these feature?

```
This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSMicrophoneUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.
```

Comment: I'm not sure if we can find which one, but maybe by giving us your podFile, we may help you. For instance, there is a talk about this for FireBase/Google Ads: http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.fr/2016/09/use-google-mobile-ads-sdk-7110-to.html and I guess they aren't the only one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Starting from iOS 10 and above, you'll need to add a description (reason) for using system resources via [Cocoa Keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html).

> The app's Info.plist must contain an
>   NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription key with a string value
>   explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

Add `NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription` (Privacy - Bluetooth Peripheral Usage Description) into the app .plist file and add its description -as a String-.

> The app's Info.plist must contain an NSMicrophoneUsageDescription key
>   with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

Add `NSMicrophoneUsageDescription` (Privacy - Microphone Usage Description) into the app .plist file and add its description -as a String-.

Somewhere in your app's plist file, they should be simialr to this:

[image]

Hope this helped.

Comment: I know the solution, but I want to know which framework or third party lib is using these feature. I don't need these features in my app.

Answer (score 0):

To start with, If you do not intend to use the microphone, try removing the related iOS/OS-X frameworks from your link stage in all of your project targets, and see which one (the app itself, or some of your private libraries/frameworks) fails to link. In the linker error you'll see which specific symbol is needed (hence the API that was erroneously used).

For external frameworks/dynamic libraries you're using, try otool-L on the binary in the command line. that will tell you which libraries/frameworsk this framework uses.